# wx python printing and print preview

Tags: python, wxpython

I have two question one about `python` in general and another about `Wx.python` , I am using python 3 , from example of `wxpython` printer example scripts two thing got my mind

code pastbin https://pastebin.com/PND7NsXw

1. about general in python , all function is executing without calling in same class ,I dont know what I am missing here
2. I can print one page as I want no issues but I cant like send 3 pages to the print preview

Comment: Please include the code (or the important parts if it's quite large) in your question.

Comment: the link is fixed sorry about that 
the fucntion is not called how ever I see its activated I set print('here') and it show up in the consule

Comment: def OnEndPrinting(self):
        """
        ...
        """
 
            super(My_Printout, self).OnEndPrinting()